# erlang >= R16B-03 is needed by rabbitmq-server-3.6.3-1.noarch

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq

**Despite Erlang 19 being installed, rabbitmq-server continues to complain about missing dependency.**

Executing the following command:

```
/usr/local/erlang/bin/erl
```

Results in confirmation (as far as I can tell) that a sufficient version of erlang is installed:

```
Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.0] [source] [64-bit] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V8.0  (abort with ^G)
```

Executing the following command:

```
sudo rpm -i rabbitmq-server-3.6.3-1.noarch.rpm
```

Results in the following:

```
error: Failed dependencies:
    erlang >= R16B-03 is needed by rabbitmq-server-3.6.3-1.noarch
```

Any hints on where I am going wrong? Can I instruct rabbitmq-server to find erlang at a specific path?

Answer (score 1):

check https://stackoverflow.com/a/40218299/877813, and add `--nodeps` in your `rpm` command, it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

rabbitmq won't run on erlang 19 right now. this is a known issue, but not well document - it's discussed in the google group for RMQ, though.

you'll want to use earlier version of erlang.

Comment: Hi Derick, thanks for the info. Question though... if it was an incompatible error wouldn't the message be different? The current response seems to indicate that it doesn't recognise the erlang installation?

Comment: even after installing erlang 18.3.x version I am getting the same issue. It is looking somewhere where it still finds :
[root@ggn-47-60 ~]# rpm -i /tmp/rabbitmq-server-3.6.3-1.noarch.rpm 
error: Failed dependencies:
 erlang >= R16B-03 is needed by rabbitmq-server-3.6.3-1.noarch
----
 erl --version
Erlang/OTP 18 [erts-7.3.1] [source-25741fd] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V7.3.1  (abort with ^G)