# rabbitmq-server installation CentOS - Erlang Error

Tags: centos, erlang, rabbitmq, erl

I have centos 6 and trying to install rabbitmq 3.5.3 using rpm. 
(**do not have option for yum**)

its throwing me below eror.

```
[root@osboxes CentOS]# rpm -Uvh rabbitmq-server-3.5.3-1.noarch.rpm 
warning: rabbitmq-server-3.5.3-1.noarch.rpm: Header V4 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 056e8e56: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
    erlang >= R13B-03 is needed by rabbitmq-server-3.5.3-1.noarch
```

But I have already installed erlang

```
[root@osboxes CentOS]# which erl
/usr/bin/erl
[root@osboxes CentOS]# 
[root@osboxes CentOS]# erl
Erlang/OTP 17 [erts-6.0] [source-07b8f44] [64-bit] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V6.0  (abort with ^G)
1>
```

Why is it not picking installed erlang?

Please share some advice that will help me in resolving the issue;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After googling a lot, finally below command worked for me!

```
rpm -ivh --nodeps rabbitmq-server-3.5.7-1.noarch.rpm
```

since, erlang is already installed, rabbitmq started successfully after this installation.

More details here - http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.networking.rabbitmq.general/28842